# Storyboard animation happening AFTER all the code is read. Need it to happen BEFORE

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I am willing to learn WPF and C# and I decided that the best way of learning a programming language is to think of a small project that makes sense to me and then learn the language features as I need them.

Now, I have a button on a Settings screen that is calling some methods in a helper class `HarpaEngine` that performs some IO-intensive work, so in order to give the user some feedback, I put a `<Path>` object on the screen that is supposed to start spinning when I click the button and, when the IO work is done, it should disappear. Here is the code that is performed when I click the button:

```
private void btnSaveSettings_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    // I created the Storyboard programmatically, don't think that's relevant               
    // It works though

    DoubleAnimation refreshAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    refreshAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    refreshAnimation.From = 0.0;
    refreshAnimation.To = 360.0;
    refreshAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard ();
    storyboard.Children.Add(refreshAnimation);
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(refreshAnimation, "RefreshAngle");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(refreshAnimation, new PropertyPath(RotateTransform.AngleProperty));

    //(...) Some work gets done here (...)

    RefreshIcon.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    storyboard.Begin(this);

    //HarpaEngine is my helper class
    HarpaEngine.MP3Files.Clear();

    Task deassign = Task.Run(() => HarpaEngine.DeassignMP3toHymns());
    deassign.Wait();

    Task populateMP3 = Task.Run(() => HarpaEngine.PopulateMP3Files());
    populateMP3.Wait();

    Task assign = Task.Run(() => HarpaEngine.AssignMP3toHymns());
    assign.Wait();

    Task serialize = Task.Run(() => HarpaEngine.SerializeMP3());
    serialize.Wait();

    storyboard.Stop();
    RefreshIcon.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
```

With this code, the object is never visible. I take it the object becomes visible and then invisible so fast that it is not visible to the naked eye. When I remove the last 2 lines so that the object never gets invisible, it starts animating **AFTER** all the lines are processed. By using Breakpoints, I found out that the overall process takes about 10 seconds to complete, so it would work perfectly IF the object became visible **BEFORE** processing the `Task.Run` lines. I tried using `async` and `await` instead of `Task.Run`, but either it is not the solution here or I implemented it wrongly. I read some articles on MSDN about Background Workers, but they suggested that `Task.Run` is more performant.

Some background context about my program:

It has an embedded .txt resource file where it reads all the lyrics of some 640 songs we sing in our church, then shows the list of songs in a list on `MainWindow`. It also reads a property setting that specifies a folder where all the MP3 files related to those songs are stored. The Settings window allows the user to change that folder's path, and the button in this code calls methods that scan the new folder for .mp3 files, then populates a `List<MP3file>`, so that, when the list of lyrics is displayed, it also shows a little Play button for each song to which there is a corresponding .mp3 file in the folder.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I guess the `<Path>` is only displayed after if finishes reading the whole code because the UIThread is blocked. It is an ordinary necessity but most of the examples I see about Threads and `async` deal with far more complex scenarios that are an overkill to my problem, and the suggested implementations involve advanced C# features that I don't know how to use yet.

Much appreciated all the help!

PS: Please, don't assume I know how to implement what you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it does not seem to start until after the work is done, is because you are calling Wait() on your Tasks.  That causes the thread to block until they are completed - unfortunately, that thread is your UI thread which is also responsible for spinning the wheels.  This means that you are starting the animation, immediately blocking the UI thread (causing your UI to hang), and then releasing it just after all your work is done.

Let's say you only had 1 long-running task to content with instead of three.  One solution is to turn your long running methods into methods that return Tasks, and then attached a ContinueWith callback

```
public Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => HarpaEngine.DeassignMP3toHymns()
    );
}

public void StopAnimation()
{
    //stop storyboard
}
```

Then, in your button-click

```
Task doingWork = DoSomethingAsync();
doingWork.ContineWith(OnWorkCompleted);
```

Comment: Awesome @Andrew! Didn't know about this ContinueWith method! Thank you very much!!!